# footables not sorting on all columns, whats wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

I have applied footables to a table that contains td's with input fields in them. I am using the data-value attribute on the td's so it should be sorting them but its not. Whats happening is its sorting by some of the rows such as the brand name and status but not others even though the data-value attribute is set.

I have created a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/owLbhbbd/15/

It looks like the inputs are empty but the data-value is set on the td's so should be sorting.

```
(function () {
    $("#service_group0").footable().bind({
        "footable_sorting" : function(e) {

          // return confirm("Do you want to sort by column: " + e.column.name + ", direction: " + e.direction);
        },
        "footable_sorted" : function(e) {

        },

    });

 });
```

There is simply to much html to past in here.

Comment: Have you loaded 'footable.sort.js'?

Comment: yes of course, its trying to sort but its not working on all columns only some